# Why does GNU Make have a default rule to create file.out from file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If you read the [Catalog of Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) section of the GNU Make manual, it turns out that one of the suffixes that it recognizes is `.out` and there is a built-in rule:

```
%.out: %
#  commands to execute (built-in):
    @rm -f $@ 
    cp $< $@
```

This means that if you have a file `xyz` in a directory, you can create `xyz.out` by simply typing `make xyz.out`.

My question is (two variants of the same question):

- Who benefits from this rule?
- In what circumstances is this used by people?

---

Obviously, I'm asking because I managed to run foul of the rule.  I had some rules like:

```
test.01: ${PROGRAM} ${DRIVER} test.01.tst test.01.out ${DATA.01}
    ${DRIVER} ${D_FLAGS} $@
```

where the name `test.01` is a phony target, but one of the dependencies is `test.01.out`.  When actively run (not using `make -n`; that works fine), this gives me lots of errors like:

```
make[1]: Circular test.01 <- test.01.out dependency dropped.
```

I also tried dropping the `.out` suffix with:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .sh
```

and that didn't seem to neuter the `.out` rule like I expected.  Is that an expected feature of GNU Make?

I guess I'm going to have to work around this <s>bug</s> feature of GNU Make by changing my suffix to `.req` or something similar, but it is a nuisance and I'm left puzzled about why the `.out` rule is part of the standard GNU Make rule set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your questions about the use of this rule.  All I can say is that this rule already existed when GNU make was first checked into source control, in Jan 1992.  It's not mentioned in any ChangeLog so probably it dates back to the very earliest versions.

The actual rule is defined as a pattern rule, so changing `.SUFFIXES` won't help.  To get rid of it you can use:

```
%.out : %
```

(no recipe) which will delete the pattern rule.

Comment: Thanks.  So, the answer (if there is one) is lost in the mists of time — I wish I could say I'm surprised, but I'm not.  The information about how to suppress the pattern rule is helpful; thank you for that.  The confirmation that futzing with `.SUFFIXES` won't help suppress pattern rules is also helpful.  (And I take it, by inference, that you don't yourself use the rule to create files — no surprise there, either!)

Comment: I personally don't use any buit-in rules in my makefiles.  In my experience they are only useful for the simplest environments.  Generally I always find I need to redefine the compile patterns to add new variables, and the others just waste time.  So, my makefiles usually contain stanzas to remove all built-in rules.

Comment: If you wanted to know the reason for `.out` you'd have to ask either Roland McGrath or RMS :)

Comment: @MadScientist or maybe the Unix gods themselves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out  - in particular look at reference 3

Comment: No, it's not related to `a.out`.  From Jonathan's question you can see that the recipe for this is not a link line but a copy command.  Also, a pattern like `%.out : %` would create a file `a.out` from a prerequisite `a` which is clearly not correct for compiling a program.  GNU make does have a built-in pattern for linking a program, but it's `% : %.o` which would build `foo` from `foo.o`.

Comment: @MadScientist you are right, don't know why I read it the wrong way around.